Downloading and executing 32 or 64bit module and execute it silently during the InnoSetup
My InnoSetup installer needs to download and execute 3rd party module silently. This module has both the 32 and 64bit exe versions with different download URLs available.
The selection of exe needs to be done based on the operating system, and the module needs to be executed after the innosetup is done.
How can this be done so that setupper displays some progress bar since the downloaded file is large ?
Earlier there was InnoTools Downloader, is it any more nowadays recommended for this, I think it had this kind of syntax:
procedure DownloadThirdPartyModule();
var
  Success: Boolean;
begin

   if IsWin64 then URL:='64one' else URL :='abc';
  // Download the file
  Success := DownloadFile(URL, SavePath);
  if not Success then
  begin
    MsgBox('Failed to download the third-party module.', mbError, MB_OK);
    RaiseException('Download failed!');
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeSetup();
begin
  DownloadThirdPartyModule();
end;

